# Showing pdf file in dhtmlxTabbar

Tags: pdf, tabbar, dhtmlx

How to load a pdf file for viewing in a dhtmlxTabbar? I tried attachObject, but it doesn’t work

Answer (score 0):

You need attachURL method:

```
tabbar.tabs("t1").attachURL("../__docs/LR1160_US.pdf");
```